# Custom grid system with Susy

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I would like to create a bootstrap like, simple grid system with susy.

My susy settings:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    gutters: 1/4,
    gutter-position: inside,
    global-box-sizing: border-box,
);
```

SASS:

```
[class^="col-"].last {
    @include last();
}

[class^="col-"].nest {
    padding:0;
}

@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-#{$i} {
        @include span($i of 12);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="left" class="col-6">left</div>
<div id="right" class="col-6 last nest">
    <div class="col-6">right 1</div>
    <div class="col-6 last">right 2</div>
</div>
```

The problem is the padding, inside the nested div. The padding on the `#left` and `#right` div is good, but the divs (`#right > .col-6`) inside `#right` are smaller, because susy use percentage as padding.

Is there a way to use susy this way?

Answer (score 1):

Susy has a mixin called "nested". [Susy documentation](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/toolkit/#nested-context)

I believe this is what you are looking for to maintain the original gutters and column sizes.

Comment: I would like to use the 'grid system' without modification in the future. I would like to re-use the code for modules what requires columns.(galleries, news blocks, portfolio, etc)

The nested mixin removes the padding, and I already did it in my code. My problem is the padding difference in the nested columns.

Comment: The `nested` mixin does not remove any padding — the `nest` keyword does.The `nested` mixin actually changes the context for nested blocks, which is what you need. But watch out, nested classes get exponentially complex. See: http://sassmeister.com/gist/ericam/0be8e9a3806ad3757bdf